# Make a JList expand to fill control?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlist

Is there anyway a JLIst can be set to expand to fit the size of the container/panel. Even if it adds empty white space its better than having odd sizes every time the amount of data changes.

Thanks

Comment: use a decent LayoutManager ;-)

Comment: Thanks :) used BorderLayout and added to the center. If you answer i will mark yours correct

Comment: I suspect that @kleopatra regards BorderLayout as 'indecent'.  ;)

Comment: @Andrew not if the requirement is simple enough :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a LayoutManager which fits your needs :-)

To elaborate a slight bit (so nobody is missing the sermon :), whenever there are problems (expected vs. actual behaviour) in sizing/positioning components, the answer is *LayoutManager*. All core implementations behave differently, out-in-the-wild they are often lacking - too simple, not powerful enough, not flexible enough ... At the end of the day, it's worth it to give any of the big-three (Form-, Mig- or DesignGridLayout) a thorough look (the learning curve is not exactly flat) and then stick to it. My current personal favourite is Mig, followed by Form and Design.